# how to store metadata with numpy array compressed with blosc

Tags: python, numpy, blosc

I am currently compressing a numpy array using blosc with the following:

```
view = memoryview(large_np_arr)
compressed = blosc.compress(view, typesize=8)
```

and decompressing like so:

```
decompressed = blosc.decompress(compressed_view)
decompressed_arr = np.frombuffer(decompressed, dtype=np.float64)
```

np.frombuffer() returns a 1-d array.  Is there anyway or standard pattern for including the array's metadata (e.g. shape, type) in the compressed view?

[I know there is blosc.pack_array(), but this make a copy of the data when pickling, which I would like to avoid.]

Comment: `np.save` writes a block with that metadata in addition to the data buffer.

Comment: yes, but I believe np.save() writes to a file or file-like object, which I'd like to avoid because it duplicates the array data in-memory.

Comment: but that's the only place where both are available in one contiguous block.

Comment: np.save() invokes format.write_array(fid, arr,...) where fid is any file-like object (e.g. BytesIO buffer), and it first writes the header and then the raw data.  I think that may be the way to go.  The format module also has read_array(). Thanks.

Comment: Argh, but format.write_array() would still create another copy of the data :(. I rather somehow find a way to prepend the _array_header, and then use the memoryview of the array.

Comment: I found that the package bloscpack does exactly what I need.  It has the ability to compress a numpy array with its metadata without making an extra copy of the data.